# Subtyping when type argument is a parameterized type

Tags: java, subtyping, parameterized-types

Say we have `List<List<String>>` and `List<List<?>>`.

Obviously, the type argument ? contains the type argument String, and hence, `List<?>` is a direct supertype of `List<String>`.

However, how does subtyping work when the type arguments are parameterized type. So, is `List<List<?>>` a supertype of `List<List<String>>`? And if yes, why?

Comment: *Obviously, the type argument ? contains the type argument String, and hence, `List<?>` is a direct supertype of `List<String>`*: no. Generics in java don't work like that.

Comment: What do you mean by `[parametrized-type]`? There is no such thing in Java...

Comment: @ernest_k
Yes, that is how it works. Cf. §4.10 of JLS.

Answer (score 1):

`List<List<?>>` is **not** a supertype of `List<List<String>>`.

`List<List<?>>` means that this object is a list, containing lists of *unknown* objects.

`List<List<String>>` means that this object is a list, containing lists of `String` objects.

As you can see, in the first example the list can contain any object, not necessarily supertypes of `String`.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, here's some detailed explanation.

The question mark (?) means: "any possible type of object" or "any object extending `Object` and the `Object` itself". Roughly you can consider `List<?>` as `List<Object>`.

Is `Object` a supertype of `String`? Yes, it is. But consider this example:

```
class A {

}

List<A> list1 = new ArrayList<>();                 
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> unknownList = list1;
```

Does it mean that `unknownList` contains objects of String's supertypes?  **No**.
It only means that this list may contains any object which extends `Object` or `Object` itself and should be treated accordingly.

Comment: Mh, but why is List<?> a supertype of List<String> while List<List<?>> is not a supertype of List<List<String>>?

Comment: What makes you think `List<?>` is a supertype of `List<String>`? You do not know what object types `List<?>` contains. Just do not know. So you can not say if it's a supertype or not.

Comment: §4.10 of the JLS.

According to this, the set of types denoted by the type argument "String" is a subset of the set of types denoted by the type argument "? extends Object" and thus, the latter type argument contains the former one, so that List<?> is a supertype of List<String>.

Besides, this compiles just fine. Am I getting sth wrong?

Comment: Yes. But nevertheless: List<?> is formally a supertype of List<String>. The meaning of the two types is clear.

However, this does not help wrt the original question :/

Comment: @chipsmonster91, once again: **List<?> is not a supertype of List<String>**. List<String> is just assignable to List<?>. List<?> - is a list of **unknown** objects, and you can not tell which objects exactly. It can be Integers, Longs, whatever. Integer is not a supertype of String, which means List<?> is not a supertype of List<String> since List<?> can actually be List<Integer>

Comment: If it is assignable without an explicit cast, it is a widening reference conversion and this requires that List<?> is a supertype of List<String>. This is confirmed here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html.

Comment: The variable type is List<Object>, which is a supertype of List<String>, but the content of the list can be, for example, a subtype of String (String is a final class, but just for example), and it's still valid, since List<Object> is a supertype of any String's subtype. That's what generics are. But, you can not make an assumption that the content of List<?> is always a supertype of List<String> or supertype of anything. It can be a subtype or absolutely different object (which is still a subtype to `Object`, and that's what confuses you).

Comment: No, that's not confusing me at all. You were wrong about the fact that List<?> would not be a supertype of List<String>, but it is.

Comment: @chipsmonster91, `List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();` I'm not sure this list is a supertype of `List<String>`... Or even this list: `List<?> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` I'm not even sure that this is a list of objects, cause this will give a compile error: `List<Object> list2 = list;`

Comment: Where is your problem / misunderstanding?

List<?> is clearly a supertype of ArrayList<Integer> (easy to prove). Your second expression statement does not compile, since List<Object> is not a supertype of List<?>.

What is your question exactly?

Besides, I figured out why List<List<?>> is not a supertype of List<List<String>>. The reason is that for checking if one type argument contains another it must be true that either (i) the types are equal or (ii) at least one type argument is (a bounded or unbounded) wildcard.

Comment: Since (i) and (ii) are false here, List<?> does not contain List<String> and vice-versa.

Comment: @chipsmonster91, if you're comparing *references*, it's ok to assume that "List<?> is a supertype of ArrayList<Integer>". But the same can not be applied to *objects* pointed by the references.

Comment: Well, when the objects are created at runtime, type arguments have already been erased. So, the question would not make sense if I would have meant objects.